# Events not shown when defaultView is agendaWeek or agendaDay

Tags: jquery, json, fullcalendar

I needed to change an existing project using FullCalendar and I've done that successfully. After those changes I have an issue when I try to change the value of `defaultView` to `agendaWeek` or `agendaDay`

When I try to use those views, the calendar doesn't show any events. If I use `basicWeek` or `month` I see the events correctly.

What might be the issue?

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    theme: true,
    //editable: true,
    allDaySlot: false,
    allDayDefault: false,
    monthNames: ['Janvier', 'Février', 'Mars', 'Avril', 'Mai', 'Juin', 'Juillet', 'Aout', 'Septembre', 'Octobre', 'Novembre', 'Décembre'],
    monthNamesShort: ['janv.', 'févr.', 'mars', 'avr.', 'mai', 'juin', 'juil.', 'aout', 'sept.', 'oct.', 'nov.', 'déc.'],
    dayNames: ['Dimanche', 'Lundi', 'Mardi', 'Mercredi', 'Jeudi', 'Vendredi', 'Samedi'],
    dayNamesShort: ['Dim', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mer', 'Jeu', 'Ven', 'Sam'],
    //hiddenDays: [ 1, 3, 5 ],
    //defaultView: 'agendaWeek',

    editable: false,
    slotMinutes: 5,



    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    titleFormat: {
        // month: 'MMMM yyyy',
        week: "d[ MMMM][ yyyy]{ - d MMMM yyyy}",
        day: 'dddd d MMMM yyyy'
    },


    columnFormat: {
        month: 'ddd',
        week: 'ddd d',
        day: ''
    },
    axisFormat: 'H:mm',
    timeFormat: {
        '': 'H:mm',
        agenda: 'H:mm{ - H:mm}'
    },
    buttonText: {
        today: 'aujourd\'hui',
        day: 'jour',
        week: 'semaine',
        month: 'mois'
    },

    weekends: true,
    minTime: '7:00',
    maxTime: '22:00',
    events: "ajax/ajax.php?action=listconference",
    eventRender: function (event, element, view) {

        if (view.name === "agendaDay") {
            element.find(".fc-event-inner").append('<br/> Voyant(e) :' + event.NomAgent + ' ' + event.PrenomAgent + '<br>');
        }
        if (view.name === "agendaWeek") {

            element.find(".fc-event-inner").append('<br/> Voyant(e) :' + event.NomAgent + ' ' + event.PrenomAgent + '<br>');
        }
        if (view.name === "month") {
            element.find(".fc-event-inner").append('<br/> Voyant(e) :' + event.NomAgent + ' ' + event.PrenomAgent + '<br>');    
        }
        if (event.allDay === 'true') {
            event.allDay = true;
        } else {
            event.allDay = false;
        }
    },
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,

    select: function (start, end, allDay) {


        if(start < date) {
            alert('Cannot select past dates.');
            return;
        }

        else if(start >= date){
        var min = dateDiff(start, end);
        findforfait(Agent,min);
        $("#box").dialog("open");
        if (initmodel()) {
            $("#datedebut").val($.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "dd/MM/yyyy"));
            $("#datefin").val($.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "dd/MM/yyyy"));
            $("#date").val($.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "yyyy-MM-dd"))
            $("#heuredebut").val($.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "HH:mm"));
            $("#heurefin").val($.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "HH:mm"));
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
        }
    }
    },      
});
```

Comment: You should take a look at the response from "ajax/ajax.php" with the help of fiddler or chrome dev tools. Do you have a valid response?

Comment: Thank U a lot, i have already fixed the problem with verifing the reponse of the method called by ajax/ajax.php